# Functions that are completely invariant under scaling

Tags: functions

I am looking for some functions that are completely invariant under scaling.

That is, a function $f(x):\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, such that $f(\lambda x)=f(x)$ for any $\lambda(>0)$.

I have come up with
$$f(x) = c$$
$$f(x) = g\left(\frac{x}{\mathbf{1}^{T}x}\right)$$ where $\mathbf{1}$ is a vector of all ones,
$$f(x) = g\left(\sum_{i}a_ix_1^{m_{i1}}x_2^{m_{i2}}\cdots x_n^{m_{in}}\right)$$
such that $\sum_{j=1}^{n}m_{ij}=0,\forall i$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [Homogeneous Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function) with degree $k=0$.

$f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ is homogeneous with degree $k\in\mathbb Z$ if $f(\lambda\vec x)=\lambda^kf(\vec x)$.

For example, $f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ or $f(\vec x)=\frac{p(\vec x)}{q(\vec x)}$, where $p(\vec x)$ and $q(\vec x)$ are both homogeneous functions of the same degree.

Answer (score 0):

Constants are trivially a solution with those properties.

Regarding your second solution: You cannot divide by a vector.